# What does "Locked Messages" mean?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms, htc-evo-3d

When I try to delete a message, I get prompted to select whether to "Delete locked messages".

There doesn't appear to be any difference if I check this option or leave it unchecked.

Does anyone know what that means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can lock a particular message in your conversation so you don't accidentally delete that. The check box is for those messages. See following screen-shots -

1. First Long tap on the message you want to lock, and select **Lock**.
2. The message should be now locked and a lock icon should appear at the bottom.
3. Now when you delete the conversation the message was in, **the locked message would not get deleted if the check-box is not selected.**

[image: Step 1] [image: Step 2] [image: Step 3] [image: Step 4]

Answer (score 1):

You can lock messages that you want to retain in your phone. IIRC long pressing the message will give you the option to lock the message.